# How to disable cursor while dragging?

Tags: css, cursor

I can disable cursor with *cursor: none*, but the cursor is still visible when dragging (moving the cursor while mouseDown). Is there any option to disable it?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Ok, I solved it myself, it was caused by the body _display: table_ property, look [here](http://examples.vsechno-atd.cz/draggingCursor.php). I don't know why it is so, thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:active` pseudo-class:

```
a:active { cursor:none /* or some other value */; }
```

documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:active